# Highlight labels/flet/macrolet definitions in lisp-mode

Tags: syntax-highlighting, common-lisp

I found this solution (https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2012-03/msg00322.html, fully cited below), but it isn't working as expected. It highlights only the first definition inside labels/flet/macrolet.

[image]

... and here the source code of the example for reproduction:

```el
(defun fn ()
  (labels ((%fn0 ())
           (%fn1 ())
           (%fn2 ())))
  (flet ((%fn0 ())
         (%fn1 ())
         (%fn2 ())))
  (macrolet ((%fn0 ())
             (%fn1 ())
             (%fn2 ()))))
```

I am wondering if there is a working solution to highlight in-function definitions?

Full quotation of https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2012-03/msg00322.html:

```el
;; Highlighting of flet/labels/macrolet local functions/macros with
;; font-lock-function-name-face

(defun mm/match-labels (bound)
  (when (re-search-forward "(\\<\\(labels\\|flet\\|macrolet\\)\\>" bound t)
    (let ((local-functions '())
          (all-start (match-beginning 0))
          (all-end (match-end 0))
          (kw-start (match-beginning 1))
          (kw-end (match-end 1))
          (parse-sexp-ignore-comments t))
      (catch 'done
        (condition-case e
            (progn
              ;; go inside the local functions list
              (goto-char (scan-lists all-end 1 -1))
              (while t
                (save-excursion 
                  ;; down into local function definition
                  (goto-char (scan-lists (point) 1 -1))
                  (let* ((name-end (scan-sexps (point) 1))
                         (name-start (scan-sexps name-end -1)))
                    (push name-end local-functions)
                    (push name-start local-functions)))
                ;; advance to the next local function
                (goto-char (scan-sexps (point) 1))))
          (error
           ;; (message "got error %s" e)
           (throw 'done nil))))
      (set-match-data (append
                       (list all-start all-end
                             kw-start kw-end)
                       (nreverse local-functions)
                       (list (current-buffer))))
      (goto-char all-end)
      t)))

(font-lock-add-keywords
 'lisp-mode
 `((mm/match-labels
    (1 font-lock-keyword-face nil)
    (2 font-lock-function-name-face nil t)
    (3 font-lock-function-name-face nil t)
    (4 font-lock-function-name-face nil t)
    (5 font-lock-function-name-face nil t)
    (6 font-lock-function-name-face nil t)
    (7 font-lock-function-name-face nil t)
    (8 font-lock-function-name-face nil t))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code from https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2012-03/msg00322.html the `push`es are in wrong order.
The code below with corrected order of the `push`es works as it is expected to work.

But, be aware that the code is very experimental.
It just fontifies seven function definitions (subexpressions of the match).

Maybe, a better implementation would be based on an anchored highlight (see the documentation of variable `font-lock-keywords`). But, that is only a guess. I think it would even be better to use a proper lisp reader for parsing.

```el
(defun mm/match-labels (bound)
  (when (re-search-forward "(\\<\\(labels\\|flet\\|macrolet\\)\\>" bound t)
    (let ((local-functions '())
          (all-start (match-beginning 0))
          (all-end (match-end 0))
          (kw-start (match-beginning 1))
          (kw-end (match-end 1))
          (parse-sexp-ignore-comments t))
      (catch 'done
        (condition-case e
            (progn
              ;; go inside the local functions list
              (goto-char (scan-lists all-end 1 -1))
              (while t
                (save-excursion 
                  ;; down into local function definition
                  (goto-char (scan-lists (point) 1 -1))
                  (let* ((name-end (scan-sexps (point) 1))
                         (name-start (scan-sexps name-end -1)))
                    (push name-start local-functions)
                    (push name-end local-functions)))
                ;; advance to the next local function
                (goto-char (scan-sexps (point) 1))))
          (error
           ;; (message "got error %s" e)
           (throw 'done nil))))
      (set-match-data (append
                       (list all-start all-end
                             kw-start kw-end)
                       (nreverse local-functions)
                       (list (current-buffer))))
      (goto-char all-end)
      t)))

(font-lock-add-keywords
 'lisp-mode
 `((mm/match-labels
    (1 font-lock-keyword-face nil)
    (2 font-lock-function-name-face nil t)
    (3 font-lock-function-name-face nil t)
    (4 font-lock-function-name-face nil t)
    (5 font-lock-function-name-face nil t)
    (6 font-lock-function-name-face nil t)
    (7 font-lock-function-name-face nil t)
    (8 font-lock-function-name-face nil t))))
```

Comment: Thank you for fixing the code and also for making my question more readable! 
I do understand that it only colors seven definitions, but since it is rather rare to have more than seven in-function definitions (at least in the codebase I'm working with), that will do.